# Factorization theorem concerning poles of a function of one complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

The following theorem was proved in my complex analysis course :

> **Thm (factorization)** : Let $D$ be a domain and let $a \notin D$ be an isolated singularity of $f \in H(D)$.
>   $$ a \text{ is a pole of order } k \text{ of } f \\
> \Updownarrow \\
> \exists g \in H(D \cup \{a\}) \text{ such that } g(a) \neq 0 \text{ and } f(z) = (z-a)^{-k} g(z) \text{ on } D$$

The proof relies on Laurent and Taylor expansions and my question is : why is the connectedness of $D$ essential in the above theorem ?

Comment: By "connexity" do you mean "convexity" or "connectedness"?

Comment: Connectedness ! Sorry, my first language is French ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectedness of $D$ is not at all important for that result. If $D$ consists of multiple components, you have the exact same representation.

But since the parts of a holomorphic function defined on a disconnected open set have nothing to do with each other, it is customary to only consider domains (connected open sets). On disconnected open sets, you don't have the identity theorem (only for each component on its own), the maximum principle, a nonconstant holomorphic function need not be an open map (it can be constant on each component, or on some components but not others).

The only important part of the representation

$$f(z) = (z-a)^{-k}g(z)$$

is on the component of $a$.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you very much.

Comment: De rien, vous êtes bienvenu. (I hope I got the accord right)

Comment: No "s" to bienvenus ! :P

Comment: Dommage. Look, it's gone ;)